# Freeradius Version

Tags: 15.10

I have noticed that the freeradius package in the repository is still 2.1.12 which is very old, and no longer supported.  Are you planning to update the repositories with a more current version?

Comment: That should have read 2.1.12 rather than 2.1.10.  But still very old.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The majority of users here is not affiliated with Canonical or active in development or packaging. I suggest you propose this on the [ubuntu-devel](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-devel) mailing list. Or you could create your own PPA with the latest release ;) PS: There's an edit button.

Answer (score 1):

- 15.10 will not get a newer version.
- 16.04 will have 2.2.

Funny: http://freeradius.org/download.html 2.1 and 2.2 are already end of life...

If you want 2.2 you can download the [installer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/freeradius) and have Ubuntu software center install it. Do check upfront if it does not want to do a complete upgrade. 3.0 though I did not see an installer for so if you want that one you will need to install it from [source](ftp://ftp.freeradius.org/pub/freeradius/freeradius-server-3.0.10.tar.bz2) yourself.